# Why do Outlook Rich Text Attachments Show Up in Line with Text?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

Whenever I have to include an attachment with an Outlook email and use Rich Text format, Outlook wants to put the attachment somewhere inline with the text.  I don't like that and would much rather it show up in the attachments box, as it does when sending in HTML format.

Is this possible somehow?

I can't use HTML for these emails because I also need to have an embedded spreadsheet, which is only supported when using Rich Text.

Comment: Note that if you create a message initially with the HTML format, add an attachment, then change the message format to Rich Text, the attachment will be placed at the very bottom of your email (below both your signature and any quoted prior messages).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft decided Outlook Rich Text was going to work that way. Attachments only go into Attached field if you use Plain Text or HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to insert the image content I wanted to insert (in Rich Text format), and then change to HTML format, to add my attachment to appear under the subject line & not in the email content. The format of what I had inserted under Rich Text was still intact & sent & received in the format I wanted.
If I started in HTML I could not insert the content the way I wanted, but once inserted under Rich Text, I was able to switch to HTML & maintain what was inserted in format I wanted.